# How to take text input in win2d just like we do in uwp with TextBox?

Tags: uwp, direct2d, win2d

How to take text input in win2d like we do in uwp with TextBox?

Comment: Win2D https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D isn't about input, just about 2D graphics rendering.

Answer (score 1):

As Simon Mourier said, Win2D is use to 2D graphics rendering. if you want to get text value, please use variable to store `DrawText` string parameter. And the other way is use `OcrEngine`  to recognize specific text. For more detail please refer this [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/OCR).